# Apply sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler to mixed numeric/categorial data frame

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In a data frame (numpy.ndarray) that contains both categorial attributes encoded as integers and numeric features using [sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html). What is the most elegant way of implementing this?

Comment: Just split the frame into the numerical columns and the categorial ones and apply the scaler only on the numeric values. Afterwards merge things. If you want to do this in a pipeline using the standard interfaces, you could just wrap the logic behind a custom transformer as explained [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator).

Comment: If the categorical attributes are one hot encoded, then the standardScaler will not touch them